# How to compare 2 different lists values in SCSS?

Tags: arrays, list, sass, breakpoints

```
$mq-grid: (
  xs: 576px,
  sm: 768px,
  md: 992px,
  lg: 1200px
)!default;


$bp-fonts: (
  .6rem, 
  1.1rem, 
  1.24rem, 
  1.4rem
);
```

For example, I have 2 different `$map`s like the above.

when the `$map` blocks set like that, is it possible to compare indexes from 2 different $map lists in SCSS?

The code I imagine is like this:

```
@for $i from 0 to length($bp-fonts) {
  @if mq-grid $val == $bp-fonts[$i] {
    // contents go here
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want, for example, that if I am on xs screen width, the font-size will be .6rem? If I well understood your problem, maybe a nested map is a better way to create this correlation.

Comment: @ReSedano Ah thanks. I'll try it