# How to get array's length & indexes that nested into $map in SCSS?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, indexing, sass, nested

In SCSS, I'm trying to get the indexes that nested another `$map`.

I have a map that looks like:

```
$bp-values: (
    width: (
        200px, 300px, 400px, 500px
    ), // array.
    font-size: (
        20px, 30px, 40px, 50px
    )
);
```

And this is how I tried to get the indexes in @function

```
@function test($map, $keys...) {

    @each $val in $keys {

        @for $val from 0 to length($map) {
            #{$keys}: $val;
        }
    }
    @return $map;
};
```

The function doesn't work when I add `@for` method like that. I've been searching on google about this issue but got no solutions at all.

Is anyone know how to get array's indexes that is inside of the $map (nested) in SCSS?

Comment: Hi calmwave. Is your problem connected to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516944/how-to-compare-2-different-lists-values-in-scss? What are you trying to do? What is the output you want?

Comment: @ReSedano Hi ReSedano, thanks to comment again. Yes this question is related my previous question.

Comment: @ReSedano I'm trying to make my own plugin that makes `@media` queries automatically on single line.

Comment: @ReSedano The basic concept is for example, if I write on my SCSS like this: `@include media-module($bp-values, width);`, then the `@media queries` go to create the number of $values in the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want loop on every item of your lists in your map, you could do something like this:

```
$bp-values: (
    width: (
        200px, 300px, 400px, 500px
    ), 
    font-size: (
        20px, 30px, 40px, 50px
    )
);

@mixin media-module($map, $key){
  $myList:map-get($map, $key);

  @each $myItem in $myList {
    $i: index($myList, $myItem);
    .someElement-#{$i} { 
        #{$key}: $myItem;
    }
  }
}
```

And then include that mixin:

```
div{
  @include media-module($bp-values, width)
}

div{
  @include media-module($bp-values, font-size)
}
```

Your output will be:

```
div .someElement-1 {
  width: 200px;
}
div .someElement-2 {
  width: 300px;
}
div .someElement-3 {
  width: 400px;
}
div .someElement-4 {
  width: 500px;
}

div .someElement-1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
div .someElement-2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
div .someElement-3 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
div .someElement-4 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```